# deploying mern app in heroku, getting this below error

Tags: heroku, mern, developer-tools

> npm ERR! Failed at the bloggers_den@1.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Any help would be appreciated,

Application Logs

> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.357332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! blog-mern@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.357496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.357639+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.357716+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the blog-mern@1.0.0 start script.
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.357838+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.366753+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.370697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.370868+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-06T05_33_29_358Z-debug.log
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.443928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2021-07-06T05:33:29.564352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

server/package.json

```
{
  "name": "blog-mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "server-install": "npm install",
    "client-install": "cd client && npm install",
    "install-all": "concurrently \"npm run server-install\" \"npm run client-install\"",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gitignore": "^0.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.14",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api/" 
}
```

Folder Structure:

Blog-mern
    client folder
    added server folder

Comment: "There is likely additional logging output above." Is there?

Comment: @ceejayoz I've added some additional details to my query.. I hope this will help...